# How to determine which window manager (and desktop environment) is running

Tags: xorg, window-manager

Is there any way (such as a command or environmental variable) to determine what **window manager** is the one actively running in the current session?

Answer (score 191):

If you have `wmctrl` installed,  the first line of output from command

```
wmctrl -m
```

will show you the name of the window manager.   If you don't have `wmctrl` installed, use the following command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Note, `man wmctrl` (that is, the `man` page for `wmctrl`) says in part:

> `-m`  Display information about the window manager ...

On my Ubuntu 11.10 / Linux 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu x86_64 / metacity 2.34.1 system, the first line of output from `wmctrl -m` was:  `Name: Metacity`
while `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` showed `ubuntu-2d` and `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` showed `Unity`.

On a fresh Ubuntu 15.10 install of `Ubuntu desktop` software on an old laptop, the first line of output from `wmctrl -m` was: `Name: Compiz`
while the `DESKTOP_SESSION` and `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` values were `ubuntu` and `Unity`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work over ssh even if X11 is enabled.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat on ubuntu 15.04, running `ssh -Y {host} 'wmctrl -m'` does return some values (e.g., "Name: Compiz", and several N/A's), but it makes sense that `ssh` would have limited info about the window manager.

Comment: on debian running cinnamon, this does not work. output of wmctrl -m is
Name: Mutter(Muffin)

while $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=X-Cinnamon

Comment: On Xubuntu Wily, running Window Maker 0.95.6 - wmctrl reports N/A for all entries. GDMSESSION is set to wmaker-common but XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP isnt set at all.

Comment: @Mei, do you have Window Maker running on any other systems you can compare?  Also, do either of  `wmctrl -d` (List all desktops managed by the window manager) or  `wmctrl -l` (List the windows being managed by the window manager) work ok on Xubuntu Wily with Window Maker?

Comment: Note to wanderers from outside Ubuntu. On RedHat wmctrl is available from the nux-dextop repo (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447999/identify-and-restart-gnome-classic-window-manager-on-rhel7)

Comment: @SridharSarnobat, the XServer runs on the local system so you don't need to ssh to it.  If you are running Windows (no Xserver) then ssh'ing into a remote server your connection will not likely be associated with a display.

Comment: The last line says:`Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF`. What does it mean?

Comment: @Timo Per [_NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#idm45643490151936) entry in  "Extended Window Manager Hints" at freedesktop.org, if that were on, windows would be hidden, with only the desktop background displayed and focused.  Maybe not an everyday need.

Comment: How a friendly clarification: Really `$DESKTOP_SESSION` returns the **Window Manager** - that is the correct answer. - for more details see - https://askubuntu.com/a/125072/970554 - and `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` returns the **Desktop Environment**

Answer (score 152):

On Linux systems I tested environment variables `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `GDMSESSION` and got the following results.

> You can use this line to get the output:
>
> ```bash
> printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"
> ```

## Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 (Ubuntu on GNOME)

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME`
- `GDMSESSION=ubuntu`

## Ubuntu 18.04 (Ubuntu on Wayland)

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME`
- `GDMSESSION=ubuntu-wayland`

---

## Ubuntu 16.04

### Unity (7)

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity`
- `GDMSESSION=ubuntu`

---

## Ubuntu 14.04

### Unity running with Mir

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity`
- `GDMSESSION=ubuntu`

***Note** `MIR_SERVER_NAME` is also set*

- `MIR_SERVER_NAME=session-$NUMBER`

### Unity running without Mir

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity`
- `GDMSESSION=ubuntu`

### XFCE

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE`
- `GDMSESSION=xfce`

---

## Ubuntu 12.04

### KDE

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=`
- `GDMSESSION=kde-plasma`

### Unity 3D

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity`
- `GDMSESSION=ubuntu`

### Unity 2D

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity`
- `GDMSESSION=ubuntu-2d`

### Gnome

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME`
- `GDMSESSION=gnome-shell`

### Gnome Classic

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME`
- `GDMSESSION=gnome-classic`

### Gnome Classic (no effects)

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME`
- `GDMSESSION=gnome-fallback`

---

## Other Ubuntu based distributions

### Mint 13 (Cinnamon)

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME`
- `GDMSESSION=cinnamon`

### Mint 16 (KDE edition)

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE`
- `GDMSESSION=default`

### Mint 17 (Cinnamon)

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=X-Cinnamon`
- `GDMSESSION=default`

### Lubuntu 12.04

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXDE`
- `GDMSESSION=Lubuntu`

### [Wasta](https://www.wastalinux.org/) 14.04 / 18.04

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=X-Cinnamon`
- `GDMSESSION=cinnamon`

### [Wasta](https://www.wastalinux.org/) 14.04 using Gnome desktop.

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME`
- `GDMSESSION=gnome`

### Ubuntu Mate 18.04

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=MATE`
- `GDMSESSION=mate`

### Xubuntu 18.04

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE`
- `GDMSESSION=xubuntu`

### Kali Linux kali-rolling 2020.2

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME`
- `GDMSESSION=lightdm-xsession`

Comment: Mint 13 (Cinnamon): XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME, GDMSESSION=cinnamon

Comment: Lubuntu 12.04: XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXDE, GDMSESSION=Lubuntu

Comment: What about $DESKTOP_SESSION ? As a backup solution :)

Comment: What if I don’t use GDM?

Comment: And further it doesn’t answer what _window manager_ I use!

Comment: Really `$DESKTOP_SESSION` returns the **Window Manager** - that is the correct answer. - for more details see - https://askubuntu.com/a/125072/970554 - and `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` returns the **Desktop Environment**

Comment: @RobertSiemer in someway the answer is correct - it seems that `GDMSESSION` returns the **Window Manager** - of course we are right about that `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` returns the **Desktop Environment**

Answer (score 49):

In the terminal type `env` to see all environment variables. Some of them are:

**XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP** - Tells you what desktop environment you are using

**GDMSESSION** - Tells you what option you selected from the lightdm greeter to login.

To use them, go to the terminal and type:

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

(Will output for example 'unity' if you are using Unity)

or

```
echo $GDMSESSION
```

(Will output for example 'ubuntu' if you selected ubuntu in the login or 'ubuntu-2d' if you selected that one in the login.)

You have others if you look closer at the output of `env` like **DESKTOP_SESSION** and **COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE**

Since what you are looking for is the name of what Window Manager is in use, the only way I see how to get this is by looking in the process list. To do this there is a command called `pgrep` ( [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep) ). I did the following to get the name since the parameter -l adds the process ID:

`pgrep -l compiz |cut -d " " -f2` since the process is running by the same user there is no need to prefix the sudo part. You can then use this to create a script that does an action based on the Window Manager.

To look for other types, just change the word `compiz` to another like `mutter`, `kwin`, etc..

Comment: Those just tell me the session name and desktop environment. Example it says "GNOME" which is a desktop environment that can use Metacity, Mutter, Compiz or other window managers. It says "gnome-classic" which is a session name, there is no such window manager with that name.

Comment: There you go. Found a command that can help with the process list. pgrep. Got to that part, at least it shows you the name of the window manager if found. Trying to check if I can add all of them together there. Your question is very good since Ubuntu 11.10 confuses a bit by using Compiz (Or mutter if when Gnome 3.x) so would be nice to point out the actual Window Manager that is used in Unity.

Comment: `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` is the current desktop environment, NOT the window manager.

Comment: it seems that `GDMSESSION` returns the **Window Manager** - and of course `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` returns the **Desktop Environment**

Answer (score 30):

I found `pstree` to be a big help.

## Installation

```
sudo apt-get install pstree
```

## output

This is what I got.

```
 ├─lightdm─┬─Xorg───2*[{Xorg}]
 │         ├─lightdm─┬─gnome-session─┬─bluetooth-apple───2*[{bluetooth-apple}]
 │         │         │               ├─compiz─┬─sh───gtk-window-deco───2*[{gtk-window-deco}]
 │         │         │               │        └─5*[{compiz}]
 │         │         │               ├─deja-dup-monito───2*[{deja-dup-monito}]
 │         │         │               ├─gnome-fallback-───2*[{gnome-fallback-}]
 │         │         │               ├─gnome-screensav───2*[{gnome-screensav}]
 │         │         │               ├─gnome-settings-───2*[{gnome-settings-}]
 │         │         │               ├─nautilus───2*[{nautilus}]
 │         │         │               ├─nm-applet───2*[{nm-applet}]
 │         │         │               ├─polkit-gnome-au───2*[{polkit-gnome-au}]
 │         │         │               ├─ssh-agent
 │         │         │               ├─telepathy-indic───2*[{telepathy-indic}]
 │         │         │               ├─update-notifier───2*[{update-notifier}]
 │         │         │               ├─vino-server───2*[{vino-server}]
 │         │         │               ├─zeitgeist-datah───{zeitgeist-datah}
 │         │         │               └─3*[{gnome-session}]
 │         │         └─{lightdm}
 │         └─2*[{lightdm}]
```

Comment: this got me there with my custom buildroot system.

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 22.04, `pstree` came pre-installed.

Answer (score 21):

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root -notype | awk '$1=="_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK:"{print $5}') -notype -f _NET_WM_NAME 8t
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Also, I think you' re missing a `)` at the end.

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen 1. `xprop -root -notype` displays all of the root window's properties (and omits types for easier parsing), the output is send to `awk` via pipe; 2. `awk` instruction `$1=="_NET[blah]CK:"{print $5}'` compares first column of each row of the input it got through the pipe with a given string and if it finds the match it runs the code in brackets which prints the fifth column from this row - just so happens (entirely by accident, I bet) to be the ID of the "_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK" atom; 3. this ID is then used again to get the properties of the Windows Manager with `xprop -id`

Comment: Does not detect ratpoision but got me headed in the right direction

Answer (score 15):

Just two cents.

```
$ sudo apt install neofetch
$ neofetch
```

[image]

Comment: +1, `neofetch` is a nifty little tool, thank you! (well, not so little, but at least it works well).

Answer (score 8):

```
#! /bin/bash


windowManagerName () {
    local window=$(
        xprop -root -notype
    )

    local identifier=$(
        echo "${window}" |
        awk '$1=="_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK:"{print $5}'
    )

    local attributes=$(
        xprop -id "${identifier}" -notype -f _NET_WM_NAME 8t
    )

    local name=$(
        echo "${attributes}" |
        grep "_NET_WM_NAME = " |
        cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=3 |
        cut --delimiter='"' --fields=2
    )

    echo "${name}"
}


windowManagerName
```

Or in one line:

> id=$(xprop -root -notype | awk '$1=="_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK:"{print
> $5}'); xprop -id "${id}" -notype -f _NET_WM_NAME 8t | grep
> "_NET_WM_NAME = " | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=3 | cut
> --delimiter='"' --fields=2

Comment: this exactly answers the question! The only answer to the question I found.

Answer (score 7):

I've been testing also with KDE and my conclusion is:

a) Graphical way, with HardInfo: the answer is normally in "Operating System" > "Desktop Environment", but if not you can look to "Environment variables". HardInfo is ready with all the tested distros, except the one with KDE, but it can be easily and quickly installed (only 2 packages in Linux Mint 13).

b) Command line, with this command: `ps -A | egrep -i "gnome|kde|mate|cinnamon|lx|xfce|jwm" -wo | sort -u`. The item that appears in more lines should be the answer (if there is a draw the item with "session" should be the solution). And it works through SSH.

Comment: XFCE also has several `gnome-...` processes (and a kde hit with `kdevtmpfs`)

Comment: @Msedfi Does not work if the WM is `lightdm`.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above actually worked for me, I just wanted to know whether I had Gnome running as my current desktop session.

This is what worked, open a terminal

```
lsb_release -a
```

(to check which flavor or version I had installed on my UBUNTU​ machine)

```
ls /usr/bin/*session
```

(launches which desktop session/desktop environment currently in use)

```
gnome-shell --version
```

(to find out which version of gnome is installed)

Comment: `ls /usr/bin/*session` showed me what was installed

Answer (score 3):

This question is 9 years old, but still topical.
On my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, I get : 
**wmctrl -m**: GNOME Shell 
**inxi -Sxx**: Desktop = Gnome 3.36.4; wm = gnome-shell; dm = GDM3 3.36.3 
**gnome-shell -- version**: 3.36.4 
**env**:GDM_SESSION : ubuntu ; DESKTOP_SESSION: ubuntu ; XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: ubuntu:GNOME 
BUT 
**xprop...** (from *ruario*): _NET_WM_NAME : GNOME Shell ; _GNOME_WM_KEYBINDINGS : Mutter, GNOME Shell ; _MUTTER_VERSION : 3.36.7 
and **neofetch**: de = GNONE ; wm = Mutter 
I deduce from this (but not very sure): **GNOME** is the desktop manager and **GNOME Shell** the window manager (Mutter must be a trace of my previous LTS versions 16.04 et 18.04).

Comment: That shows how confusing all the content and conclusions are in this entire thread. Your window manager _is_ Mutter, as pointed out very helpfully and accurately by neofetch. (I get Mutter as well on a _new install_ of 20.04, if that helps.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use tool called `inxi`. It can be obtained from Ubuntu Repositories by:

`sudo apt install inxi`

or from github : https://github.com/smxi/inxi

Just run the command as follows:

```
inxi -Sx
System:    Host: blackhole Kernel: 5.1.15-050115-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 8.3.0
           Desktop: i3 4.16.1-178-g31c0f1b8 Distro: Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo)
```

Note the `Desktop: i3` part. In my case the window manager I use is `i3`.

Option `-S` displays system info and `x` adds info about window manager.

Answer (score 0):

## Script

The following script resulted as the best answer to a similar [question I posted over at unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116539/39845). It also works great with Unity and LXDE.

```
if [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = '' ]
then
  desktop=$(echo "$XDG_DATA_DIRS" | sed 's/.*\(xfce\|kde\|gnome\).*/\1/')
else
  desktop=$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
fi

desktop=${desktop,,}  # convert to lower case
echo "$desktop"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of possible with dbus and the Accounts Service (both by default in Ubuntu).

```
$ qdbus --system org.freedesktop.Accounts \                                                                
> /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 \                                                                                     
> org.freedesktop.Accounts.User.XSession                                                                                   
ubuntu
```

Worth noting that I've tested this with logging in through lightdm (that is the graphical login screen) , it did detect a classic desktop like blackbox , and obviously detects Unity. I suspect this is a value of what user selects on the login screen as session, that's why it's a bit easier to use that checking for processes

Answer (score 0):

#### Desktop Environment lxqt (e.g. Lubuntu >= 18.10)

One way is open `~/.config/lxqt/session.conf` and find

```
[General]
__userfile__=true
window_manager=openbox // <==
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that works through SSH :

```
$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager | xargs basename
lightdm
```