# Remove arrows on system tray menus in gnome

Tags: gnome, 13.10, menu, applet, system-tray

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 with Gnome and have found the behaviour of the context menus on icons in the system tray behaves differently.

For applets which normally have a large number of menu options (e.g. notes in Tomboy or files in Dropbox) rather than display all the menu icons now only 5 or 6 are displayed and up/down arrows are displayed to scroll to the rest.

Is it possible to revert this behaviour so all menu options are showing without the need to scroll?

Comment: Which version of Gnome are you using? You can use `gnome-shell --version`

Comment: @wilf I've run that command but it says gnome-shell is not installed. I've taken a quick look at the system tray about information and it lists Indicator Applet Complete 12.10.1

Comment: Then what are you using? Ubuntu 13.10 by default use 3.8, you can use 3.10. Is it [Unity](http://askubuntu.com/a/65108/178596), [Gnome Panel](http://askubuntu.com/a/65087/178596) or something?

Comment: @wilf - I'm fairly sure I'm using Gnome Panel, but if there's some way I can confirm this let me know.

Comment: Best would be to post a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Here is a answer on how to find out which windows manager you are using [How to determine which window manager is running](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running)

Answer (score 1):

This extension/work around could be of some help if you have to get rid of the drop down menus which are default in gnome 3.8+ [gnome-shell-remove-dropdown-arrows](https://github.com/mpdeimos/gnome-shell-remove-dropdown-arrows)

Answer (score 1):

There's this awesome extension called [TopiconsPlus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/). Once installed it moves all those "legacy" icons to the menubar.