# can't see value of DESKTOP related XDG environment variables from remote machine

Tags: command-line, ssh, desktop-environments, remote-desktop, environment

- When I run echo `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` or `$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP` I can see values on my Linux machine.
- When I run same commands on my machine from **remote machine** showing empty results.

IMO, those variables are set only for its session. 
How to get which desktop environment is running on the remote machine?

I was developing an application that has a feature to check which desktop environment is running on Linux machine.

Tried (getting empty results):

```
bash -c "echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"

source ~/.profile && echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

Comment: Linux is a multi-user OS - there may be many desktop sessions running "on" it

Comment: [pa4080](https://askubuntu.com/users/566421/pa4080) wrote a great script for that, see the above linked question.

Comment: I have tried above script. Getting same EMPTY RESULT
 
`./find-DE.sh
 
user: root

uid:  0

XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: 

GDMSESSION:          `

`DESKTOP_SESSION:`

Comment: I take it you also already tried everything in https://askubuntu.com/q/72549/507051?

Comment: result: 
`Desktop:`
 
`Session:`

Comment: The `XDG...` vairables are set by the GUI session that the user runs underneath. When you access the "Remote Machine", you're not running a GUI on the "Remote Machine", so those variables should NOT be defined for your process.

Comment: @waltinator thanks, any solution? How to know which desktop env. is running there?