# 18.04 - Cannot change the background color of the LOCK screen, not the Login screen

Tags: 18.04, themes, gnome-shell, lock-screen

Good evening,

I'm trying to change some of the colours of my login screen in my Ubuntu 18.04. I followed some questions here on AskUbuntu, and edited my `css` files at `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css` (I'm using that configuration) - Specifically, I changed the values of `.lockDialogGroup` to a nicer dark gray.

My login screen is indeed now a nice dark gray instead of that hellish purple.

**However**, if I lock my computer without shutting down the machine, I still get a different purple gradient, which I haven't managed to change. I'm serching around but since I don't even know what to call this "behind-the-shield" screen, I can't find relevant results.

I suspect the login screen and the lock screen are two different managers altogether.

Here's a short `mp4` video of me literally filming my screen, to make you understand which color I'm trying to change:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdEPP.jpg

**EDIT:** There seems to be a discrepancy between my first-after-boot login screen, and my login-after-locking screen.

**first Login screen after boot:**
[image]

**After-lock login screen:**
[image]

Comment: @PRATAP Doesn't matter, I'm interested in finding where the .css that controls this gradient is located

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? The default gnome or something else? Please [edit] the output of `printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"` into your post. as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/227669/225694)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu-communitheme-snap.desktop` and change the "ubuntu-communitheme" text to "myct" (change anything, not necessarily "myct") in the line starting with `Exec=`

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu-communitheme-snap.desktop
```

[image]

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu with communitheme snap
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=myct /snap/communitheme/current/session
TryExec=/snap/communitheme/current/session
Type=Application
DesktopNames=communitheme:ubuntu:GNOME
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

create a file named myct.json in the directory `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/` with below content.

[image]

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "myct.css",
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com"]
}
```

Create a text file named `myct.css` in the directory `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`

```
sudo touch /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/myct.css
```

Open the file and paste the below content

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/myct.css
```

Content:

```
@import url("/snap/communitheme/current/share/gnome-shell/theme/Communitheme/gnome-shell.css");

#lockDialogGroup {
  background-color: magenta; }
```

Reboot and then lock the screen to see your preferred color.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100651/discussion-on-answer-by-pratap-18-04-cannot-change-the-background-color-of-the).