# Ubuntu gnome-shell purple design

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, 18.10, gdm

How do I remove Ubuntu gnome-shell theme and restore the original one? I already tried `sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css` (gnome-shell.css). However, this only done like 75% work done. The login screen is now in default gray colors as I wanted but when I suspend my computer login screen is purple again. I also see purple corners when gnome-shell is loading.

Comment: after suspend is it a login screen or unlock screen?

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question correctly, you want to go back to default theme..
you can use the same command again and select the number `0`

`sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css`

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
[sudo] password for mkr: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).

  Selection    Path                                               Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css   15        auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css   15        manual mode
* 2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css        10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css to provide /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css (gdm3.css) in auto mode
$
```

If you want to apply the changes to unlock-screen also, this answer may help.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1107377/739431

Edit:
as per the comments, you have manually deleted the folder `Yaru`
to install `yaru-theme` package run the below command,

`sudo apt install yaru-theme-gnome-shell`

```
$ sudo apt install yaru-theme-gnome-shell
[sudo] password for mkr: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
yaru-theme-gnome-shell is already the newest version (18.10.6).
yaru-theme-gnome-shell set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
$
```

It says this is already the newest version, may be because we have manually deleted the folder `Yaru`

so, `sudo apt purge yaru-theme-gnome-shell`

```
$ sudo apt purge yaru-theme-gnome-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  xwayland
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop* ubuntu-session* yaru-theme-gnome-shell*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
After this operation, 637 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Please note that the command `sudo apt purge yaru-theme-gnome-shell` will also remove ubuntu-desktop* and ubuntu-session* along with yaru-theme-gnome-shell*

Once we continue with Yes,

we need to again install ubuntu-desktop and ubuntu-session packages..

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-session`

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-session
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  yaru-theme-gnome-shell
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-session yaru-theme-gnome-shell
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 113 kB of archives.
After this operation, 637 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I already tried this. I also tried to remove other themes.

Comment: 18.10 (I have not upgraded from 18.04)

Comment: gdm3.css  gnome-shell.css

Comment: No, I have not. Already tried to reinstall Yaru but don't know package name.

Comment: I did not take backup of Yaru folder.

Comment: I managed to restore Yaru folder from squashfs of Ubuntu ISO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89165/discussion-between-richardds-and-pratap).

Answer (score 0):

You can hack at the CSS directly too.

I wrote a how-to on removing purple from the Ubuntu theme.

http://teknorants.blogspot.com/2020/01/changing-ubuntus-royale-purple.html

Answer (score 0):

Just install `gnome-session`. Then log into it (for example, "GNOME on Xorg").

Then enable Ubuntu extensions:

```
gnome-shell-extension-tool -e ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
gnome-shell-extension-tool -e ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
```

And change wallpaper for lock screen.