# 'Files' window doesn't show in taskbar when using Dash to Panel

Tags: 21.10

The 'Files' window doesn't show in the taskbar. Any other application will show when started but files does not. I'm running dash to panel on Ubuntu 21.10. Is there a setting I'm missing?

```
~$ wmctrl -m
Name: GNOME Shell
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
~$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
ubuntu-xorg ubuntu:GNOME
```

[image: Files window not showing in taskbar]
[image: Dash to panel settings]

Comment: removing and reinstalling nautilus worked for me, on the same release
sudo apt remove nautilus && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt install nautilus

Comment: It seems reinistalling works but the problem returns after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (`21.10`).
My setup :

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal

sudo apt reinstall gdm3 gnome-shell gnome-session
```

also installed

```
dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep gnome
ii  chrome-gnome-shell
```

My current environment ([from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running))

- Window manager: `wmctrl -m`
- Session: `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`
- Desktop environment: `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

For me it is i.e. `GNOME-Shell`, `ubuntu-xorg` and `ubuntu-GNOME`
`gnome-shell --version` `40.5`

All extensions installed from:

[gnome extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/)

Here my installed extensions.

```
~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions$ sudo ls -l
  drwxrwxr-x 3 user user 4096 Dez  1 18:30 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
  drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 Dez  1 18:32 clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com
  drwxrwxr-x 5 user user 4096 Dez  3 11:18 dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
  drwxrwxr-x 3 user user 4096 Dez  1 18:50 panel-date-format@keiii.github.com
  drwxrwxr-x 7 user user 4096 Apr 21  2021 stocks@infinicode.de
  drwxrwxr-x 3 user user 4096 Dez  1 18:30 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

[image: Panel Filemanager Window]

Comment: yes, followed all the steps, still nothing. Did complete re-install of Ubuntu 20.10 and dash-to-panel. Still no files window.

Comment: Sometimes `wayland` act not in the normal way. Can you test this in another envionment (`Xorg`, show `printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"` ).

Comment: It prints Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME Session: ubuntu

Comment: maybe try to switch like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10/961345#961345)

Comment: the difference to my installation seems to be, you are in an ubuntu-session and I'm in a xorg-ubuntu and my windomanager is a `gdm3` `gome-session` combination yours, I guess, `wayland` or `lightdm` and ubuntu. My advise: you can have many display/windowmanager parallel. Install `gnome-shell` and replace  `ubuntu` with `gnome-shell`.

Comment: Have you read [Howto enable Dash to Panel on github](https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/wiki/Enable-and-Customize)? There is described 




1. Reload GNOME Shell.

<br> - Xorg (Default for Ubuntu): `Alt-F2` and in the dialogue that pops up, enter the command `r`
- Wayland (Default for Fedora & Debian): Logout and back in  means: gnome-shell seems to be a prerequisite for this extension

Comment: Still no luck, gnome-shell didn't change anything, reloading it neither. If I disable Dash To Panel, open a Files window and enable it again, then it show up on the taskbar. Though if I close it, it remains running. Added some info to original post.

Comment: can you show this again
Window manager: `wmctrl -m`
Session: `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`
Desktop environment: `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Comment: I'v put the info in the original question. I also came across this https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/1265#issuecomment-947340263 guess I'm not the only one.

Comment: what is your `gnome-shell --version` and have you tried this [workaround](https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/1437#issuecomment-902875910)

Comment: mine ist 40.5 and the extension has version 44